# Python - how to pass a variable to a regular expression (re.match)

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I'm trying to pass a variable to a regular expression as the value which is being checked will change each time. So far, I can look for a given string which works but I'm not sure on the correct syntax when passing a variable.

serial string: `"asdfID:13546537(0xCEB429)"`

var: `13546537`

```
#This works with a hard coded string search      
match = re.search(r'ID:13546537(\d*)', str(serial))
print("ID value = " + match.group(1))

Var = 13546537
Var = str(Var)

#What I've tried
if match = re.search(r'ID:'+Var+, str(serial)):
    print("match found")
else:
    print("match not found")
```

SyntaxError returned which has an issue with the comma after the +Var+

Comment: `Var+,` extra `+` ?

Comment: Besides, you lost `(\d*)` somewhere, `r'ID:'+Var+r'(\d*)'`

Comment: @Bart even `==` doesn't make sense. He probably wants to assign match to `match` but that doesn't work in Python. i`if re.search(...) is not None:` would be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were quite close. You can for example use [f-strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) to place your variable inside the regex:

```
import re

var = 13546537
serial = "asdfID:13546537(0xCEB429)"

if re.search(fr"ID:{var}", serial):
    print("match found")
else:
    print("match not found")
```

> Output
>
> ```
> match found
> ```

Alternatively if you're running a Python version earlier than 3.6, you can you normal [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format):

```
import re

var = 13546537
serial = "asdfID:13546537(0xCEB429)"

if re.search(r"ID:{}".format(var), serial):
    print("match found")
else:
    print("match not found")
```

> Output
>
> ```
> match found
> ```

Comment: Hi ruohola, thanks for your response. I tried this and it works ok using IDLE but fails due to a syntax error when trying to run using command line. It doesn't like the " after {var}". Do you have this problem when you run it?

Comment: @SamL The Python version you're running from your terminal is something below 3.6, which is needed for f-strings. You can try running the command `python --version` to see what it is and then you should go and download a newer version from https://www.python.org/

Comment: Thanks, I've just checked and I'm currently running 3.7.0. I assume that should be recent enough to allow f strings to be used?

Comment: @SamL Yes that is, are you sure that you copy pasted the code correctly from here? You can also try the second way I posted.

Comment: Super job! Works well now. I see you changed the code slightly and added the .format(var). Thanks for your help.

Comment: @SamL Glad I could help! Feel free to also [mark the answer as accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/510616) if you feel like it was helpful :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199320/discussion-between-saml-and-ruohola).